# $.connection undefined in signalR

Tags: jquery, asp.net, signalr

I am trying to make a chat application using signalR. But its showing me error that $.connection is undefined.
I have added the following library to aspx class

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
     <!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
     <script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.0.0.js"></script>
     <!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
     <script src="signalr/hubs"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub. 
    var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub;
});
```

I have looked into many solutions from stackoverflow, but can not solve the issue :(

Comment: What you have looks fine - are you getting any other console errors? Can you show us more of your code?

Comment: Where is the code for your `$.connection`?

Comment: Are you using an MVC 4 project? If yes, did you already include jQuery in the page? If yes, then remove one of them.

Comment: No i am using it inside asp.net usercontrol.

Comment: Check that you are not loading the jQuery library anywhere else. If you are using an asp.net usercontrol, then you might have the script referenced in a .aspx or .master page.

Comment: i have added  jQuery.noConflict(); but still no change

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem which was resolved when i replaced

```
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

with

```
http://localhost/[myrootname]/signalr/hubs
```

Also verify whether browsing the URL:

```
http://localhost/[myrootname]/signalr/hubs
```

your browser is trying to open a static file

Comment: That's what I was looking for.